# Consulta Access via VBA

Tags: vba

Estou com uma base em Access e estou com problemas no resultado da QUERY.

Quando executo essa mesma QUERY no access, ela roda normalmente, mas quando jogo no VBA ela não dá erro, mas não retorna nenhum registro no RECORSET.

Abaixo a QUERY que estou usando:

```
Set BD = New ADODB.Connection     
BD.Open ConectaBD        
sWHERE = "WHERE (((BASE_PREMIO.UF)=""SP"") AND ((BASE_PREMIO.cliente)=""CAASP"") AND ((BASE_PREMIO.GrupoPlano)=""ESPECIAL"") AND ((BASE_PREMIO.Região)=""SUDESTE"") AND ((BASE_PREMIO.TpEntidade)=""FECHADA"") AND ((BASE_PREMIO.Corretor) Like ""*""))"        
QUERY = "SELECT BASE_PREMIO.REFERENCIA, Sum(BASE_PREMIO.Premio_Sum) AS SomaDePremio_Sum, Sum(BASE_PREMIO.Vidas_Sum) AS SomaDeVidas_Sum, Sum(IIf([DIF_MES_VENDAS_MATURADAS]>2,[PREMIO_SUM],0)) AS [VENDA MATURADA_PREMIO], Sum(IIf([DIF_MES_VENDAS_MATURADAS]>2,[VIDAS_SUM],0)) AS [VENDA MATURADA_VIDAS], Sum(IIf([VENDAS]=""S"",[PREMIO_SUM],0)) AS VENDA_PREMIO, Sum(IIf([VENDAS]=""S"",[VIDAS_SUM],0)) AS VENDA_VIDAS, Sum(IIf([VENDAS]=""N"",[PREMIO_SUM],0)) AS ESTOQUE_PREMIO, Sum(IIf([VENDAS]=""N"",[VIDAS_SUM],0)) AS ESTOQUE_VIDAS "        
QUERY = QUERY & "FROM BASE_PREMIO "        
QUERY = QUERY & sWHERE        
QUERY = QUERY & " GROUP BY BASE_PREMIO.REFERENCIA;"        
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset            
RS.Open QUERY, BD
```

Acho que o problema ocorre porque busco campos com condições específicas. Será que preciso habilitar alguma ferramenta nas referencias do vba? Ou tem outra forma de resolver esse problema?  Obrigada.